# How to run batch file from within PL/SQL procedure

Tags: sql, windows, oracle, batch-file, plsql

I have a batch file which will execute some .exe which do some operations (like connecting to DB, fetching data, insert data etc...)
All the things are configured in the batch file and when I run it, it works good.

But, I want to invoke this **batch file** from a **PL/SQL procedure**.
this procedure should invoke this batch file first, and after the execution of the batch file, it will have it's own SQL operations.

How can I proceed to do this?

Comment: Where and how is the PL/SQL supposed to be run, if the batch file makes the connection to the database - as part of a scheduled job? Is the batch file on the client or the server? And... why? What is the rationale for doing this? Why can't rhe PL/SQL (stored procedure? job?) perform the DB changes directly?

Comment: No, actually the batch file is an API of another software which connects to the database and dumps the data into it.
Here in my application i will call this procedure to export data. So I want to invoke from a PL/SQL procedure.

Comment: So, from within your application you call a procedure that in turn should run a batch file? Sounds overly complicated to me, why don't you start the batch file directly from your application? Are you aware that the batch file (and the associated .exe) needs to be stored on the filesystem of the Oracle *server* in order to be accessible?

Answer (score 1):

Set up a job with dbms_scheduler. This topic is discussed here (German):
http://db-memory.blogspot.ch/2012/12/dbmsscheduler-mit-executable-unter.html
The screenshots may be helpful.

Please remember to enable the dbms_scheduler job, else it won't run.

Answer (score -1):

You can write your own stored java class with a method which implements running an OS executable file. You should grant to your oracle user java.io.FilePermission and java.lang.RuntimePermission with DBMS_JAVA.GRANT_PERMISSION procedure. Then you should create a plsql function-wrapper which calls your java method. And all you should do for running an OS eecutable is to run your plsql wrapper function.

There is an "AskTom" page about it [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:3069633370832)