# Is it possible to call a vb.net function from a stored procedure in an Oracle DB?

Tags: .net, vb.net, oracle, plsql

I have a generic string manipulation function developed as a class as follows;

```
Public Class MyClass
  Public Function MyFunction(ByVal inString As String) As String
    Dim MyString as String = inString & " Some Stuff"
    Return MyString
  End Function
End Class
```

The real function does real stuff, but it is all string manipulation, no DB, file or screen access.

Is there an easy way to make this function callable from a procedure within a package within an Oracle DB?

I have installed Oracle DB Extensions for .NET on the DB server.

I am hoping to avoid installing anything on the computer where I develop my VB.NET code. I have created external packages using a c library (c++ DLL) before, but I was under the impression that .NET is different. Everything I find when searching seems to talk about some form of extension to VS that allows an "easy" deploy straight from .NET.

I will eventually need to deploy this on multiple DBs and want a manual process that I can just run, and not connect to each DB from my .NET development computer.

Edit:

I have an existing C++ library I call from PL/SQL. When I define the package body it looks like;

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY            "MY_PACKAGE" 
AS
   FUNCTION MY_FUNCTION (VAR1  in varchar2, VAR2 in varchar2, VAR3 in varchar2)RETURN PLS_INTEGER
   IS
      EXTERNAL 
      LIBRARY DLL_MY_LIBRARY 
      NAME "MY_FUNCTION"  
      LANGUAGE C 
      PARAMETERS (VAR1 string, VAR2 string, VAR3 string);  
END MY_PACKAGE;
```

What does the definition for a VB.NET function within a class look like? Do I need dot notation like;

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY            "MY_PACKAGE" 
AS
   FUNCTION MY_CLASS.MY_FUNCTION (VAR1  in varchar2, VAR2 in varchar2, VAR3 in varchar2)RETURN PLS_INTEGER
   IS
      EXTERNAL 
      LIBRARY DLL_MY_LIBRARY 
      NAME "MY_CLASS.MY_FUNCTION"  
      LANGUAGE VB.NET 
      PARAMETERS (VAR1 string, VAR2 string, VAR3 string);  
END MY_PACKAGE;
```

What should the language be?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: [Developing and Deploying .NET Stored Procedures](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e10767/procedures_dot_net.htm)? I guess that's what you want to avoid, right?

Comment: Yes, actually that is what I am trying to avoid. The two pieces of information I would like are, 1) Do I need to make any changes to the code. 2) How can I manually deploy it.

Comment: Have a look at [How to run batch file from within PL/SQL procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580475/how-to-run-batch-file-from-within-pl-sql-procedure). If you can get a batch file started I expect you can run just about anything. (Oh, the security issues! Oh, the humanity..!) Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried it, but at first sight, I would try something like the following:

**From Oracle Extension for .NET Developers Guide 11g Release 2**

**[Development and Deployment with Visual Studio](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17666_01/doc/win.112/e17405/devdeploy.htm)**

**[Step 5: Deploy the Procedure or Function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17666_01/doc/win.112/e17405/devdeploy.htm#CHDFDDAD)**

> Deploy the procedure or function in the database. The wizard performs the following steps:
>
> 1. Connects as SYSDBA.
> 2. Copies the user assembly to the ORACLE_BASE\ORACLE_HOME\bin\CLR directory or its subdirectory.
> 3. Creates an Oracle library object and grants execute privilege on this library object to the database user:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE LIBRARY CLRLIBRARY1_DLL AS '$ORACLE_HOME\bin\clr\CLRLibrary1_dll;
GRANT EXECUTE ON CLRLIBRARY1_DLL TO SCOTT;
```

> 4. Creates a PL/SQL wrapper in the user's database schema for each procedure or function, according to the parameter type mappings defined by the user.

Knowing exactly what the wizard does, it is according to me feasible to write a Power Shell script or the like to perform the tasks for you.

I'll continue to dig. It's an interesting feature I'm interested in.

---

**when I create the pl/sql wrapper, will I use dot notataion?**

[**Step 6 : Test the function**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14306/demo.htm#CJFJAIIH) should answer your concern.

[**Invoking from SQL*Plus**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14306/demo.htm#CEGHIDII)

> *To invoke the `GetDeptNo()` function .NET function from SQL* Plus:
>
> *Start SQL*Plus and log in as user scott with the password tiger.*
>
> *Enter the following commands:*

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
deptno BINARY_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  deptno := GetDeptNo(7934);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(deptno);
END;
```

> *Alternatively, you can execute following statement:*

```
SELECT GetDeptNo(7934) FROM DUAL;
```

So it looks to me that you won't be required to use the dot notation.

Comment: Will, I will give that a try. One question that I have is since my function is wrapped in a class, when I create the pl/sql wrapper, will I use dot notataion? I edit my question to put in more detail.

Comment: Did my humble answer help a few? Any other missing details, perhaps? =)

Comment: I tried your approach, but got errors. Logged an SR with Oracle, and the induhvidual assigned to my case has been less than helpful for the last three weeks. I have escalated it twice, and tried to get someone different with no luck.

Comment: What kind of errors have you got? Perhaps either posting another question or editing your the current could enlighten one for a potential solving.